# How to embed files separately?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to open 2 different file formats - PDF and M4V. If the file is PDF, I want to use embed tag and if it's M4V, I want to use a video tag.

The following code is the one I am using but it's showing only one of the files (depending upon the code). Has anyone any idea how to solve this?

```
$('div.player-container object').attr('data', htmlPageBrowserUri);
$('div.player-container object param').attr('value', htmlPageBrowserUri);
$('div.player-container object video' || 'div.player-container object embed').remove();
$('div.player-container object').append(
'<video src="' + htmlPageBrowserUri + '" width="100%" height="600"/>' || 
'<embed src="' + htmlPageBrowserUri + '" width="100%" height="600"/>'
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check type if type present in URL

Like 'http://yourdomain/filename.pdf' or 'http://yourdomain/?f=filename.pdf'
Or something like this that file type is present at end of url

```
 Type=htmlPageBrowserUri.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
 if(Type == 'pdf'){
 //pdf code
 }else if(Type == 'm4v'){
 // m4v code
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check for the file's extension:

```
$('div.player-container object').attr('data', htmlPageBrowserUri);
$('div.player-container object param').attr('value', htmlPageBrowserUri);
$('div.player-container object video' || 'div.player-container object embed').remove();
var elementToAppend;
switch (htmlPageBrowserUri.split('.').pop().toLowerCase()) {
    case "pdf":
        elementToAppend = "embed";
        break;
    case "m4v":
        elementToAppend = "video";
        break;
}
if (typeof elementToAppend !== 'undefined') {
    $('div.player-container object').append('<' + elementToAppend + ' src="' + htmlPageBrowserUri + '" width="100%" height="600"/>');
}
```

Comment: +1 for completeness and using switch over if/else. Unlikely that you'd add one in this instance, but just be warned that without `break`s in the switch, any added `default` action will be used for all.

Comment: @Popnoodles Thanks, I forgot to put them. Though, as you said, I wouldn't need them in this case, it's a good habit to always put them.

Comment: @MarkusHayner  This should be the accepted answer. The code is neater and it answers the question without leaving anything to be guessed, as opposed the the current accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using `||` in the jquery selector really works. Here is how you can use multiple selector: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Try following edits in your code.

```
$('div.player-container.object').attr('data', htmlPageBrowserUri);
$('div.player-container.object.param').attr('value', htmlPageBrowserUri);
$('div.player-container.object.video, div.player-container.object.embed').remove();
$('div.player-container.object').append(
'<video src="' + htmlPageBrowserUri + '" width="100%" height="600"/><embed src="' + htmlPageBrowserUri + '" width="100%" height="600"/>'
);
```

Also when you have multiple classes assign to one div like  you have to insert an identifier with each one of them. So in jQuery it would be like `$('div.player-container.object.param')` not `$('div.player-container object param')` (I may not be too good at explaining this, so see the link below)

Learn more about selectors here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp